# Doubts about technology for ios development

Tags: ios

I want to develop a **native** application to ios.

I want to build an app that is a mix of Instagram and YouTube,generally.
I need to persist and get data to and from the database,store user data(images,videos,audio etc.), Allow user to edit his uploaded media ( images,videos,audio etc.).Also things such as drag and drop, GPS and image edition are added.

So far I think these are the most demanding features that app will contain.

I think about using swift for the front end, but I am still considering what language and database to go with to develop this application.

I though I should maybe go with php laravel framework RESTful api(since I know it already), combined with firebase.

Any better suggestion you might think about, and why?

Will appreciate your honest thoughts about this.

Comment: This is a very very broad question. You better narrow it down and ask question about the specific problems that are answerable.

Comment: I really don't know what else to add to this. I was talking about the main functionalities for the app, and what I was thinking about so far, but I don't know what to say more than that. You're more than welcome to give me some suggestions about what to add to the question.

Comment: Do you need suggestions for the backend development also? If you know `PHP` then I would suggest you should go with it. Restful APIs with JSON response would do for you and they are easy to use. A lot of help is available for this. Now coming to the iOS part, you should use `CodeData` for data persistence, `AFNetworking` to call your Restful web services. Visit [this site](cocoacontrols.com) for the UI custom controls that you want in your app.

Comment: that for that comprehensive answer. And where does swift language comes to place here?

Comment: `Swift` and `Objective-C` are both native languages for `iOS` development. You'll be using either of them to create the front end of your application using `Xcode`. You are allowed to use both these languages together as well and you can find plenty of help on this topic too. What else do you want to know?

Comment: supposing I am using swift for front end , and php laravel framework RETful api for back end- I still need to use some database, and I am not sure that coredata is supported by Laravel framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125830/discussion-between-adeel-and-osherdo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was really putting the last hours in order to determine the right language for developing the back-end and the database. And I reckon that really node.js and mongoDB , along with Swift will make the perfect match!

node.js seems to be good for my app, as it does not really require very complex computing, and MongoDB is ideal for social networking features. These are the main reasons I am going with this stack :)

Also,about scalability, it's easier in MongoDB,rather than MySQL.